# Style tag in return ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have a style tag in my react js code of **return()**

```
return(
  <style> .mobile_view_svg_div{} 
                  `@media(max-width:600px){`
                    `.mobile_view_svg_div`
                    `{`
                        width:300px;
                    `}`
                   `} `
          </style>
          <div>
          <svg className="mobile_view_svg_div">
            svg code here.
          <svg>
          </div>
)
```

when I compile this , I get error as

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected }

Any help would be great.

Comment: No you can't do that. You've to add it in a css file and load that css file.

Comment: Why do you have backticks in your HTML?

Comment: @Pavan. I don't load any css file in that as it is for only 404 no found page.

Comment: @Barmar. I have searched and got one article to have a syntax like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the wrapping div on it. With that, such styling should work.

*I just added a red background so you can actually see the styling in action ;)*

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <style>{`
          .mobile_view_svg_div {
            background-color: red;
          } 
          
          @media(max-width:600px) {
            .mobile_view_svg_div {
              width:300px;
            }
          }
        `}</style>
        <div>
          <svg className="mobile_view_svg_div">
            svg code here.
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: great. it works.. thank you so much. accepting in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the return in div, works fine for me.